# Get list of values from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most pythonic way of implementing `get_values`:

```
>>> d = { 'a' : 0, 'b': 32424, 'c' : 'whatever' }
>>> get_values(d, ['a', 'c'])
[ 0, 'whatever' ]
```

Is there a builtin function to do just that? Any other accepted way?

(I *do not* want all vales, just a list of the values corresponding to the list of fields specified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a list `keys`:

```
[d[key] for key in keys]
```

Comment: Sure, right, obvious, I though there would be a ready function (a-la enumerate) for that ...